# Amazon Custom AMI

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-ami

If I create a custom AMI for an EBS backed EC2 instance after installing numerous applications and making lot of config changes to the EC2 instance like IP Tables, httpd.conf file etc...

Will the custom AMI image capture all those config changes and/or installed applications so that I can use it to launch exact functioning copy of the Custom AMI originating EC2 Instance?

Answer (score 4):

Anything done after launching an EC2 instance will be independent of what the original AMI had. There isn't a relationship among the instances which use the same AMI as well; except that they all were materialised from a single AMI - the individual / independent changes in the Instances ( AMI ) would be in silos.

Coming back to your point; after making numerous changes; you would need to create an image `AMI` out of the running instance where the changes have been made. Going forward you can use the AMI to create new instances. Already created instances wouldn't reflect any new changes.

This is where the tools like Ansible, Chef, Puppet come into picture.